# JVM Tuning - CMS behavior

Tags: garbage-collection

Currently I'm running an application in Tomcat 7 with the following jvm arguments:

```
-Dcatalina.home=E:\Tomcat
-Dcatalina.base=E:\Tomcat
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\Tomcat\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=E:\TomcatE\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=E:\Tomcat\conf\logging.properties
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:NewSize=7g
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=31
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=90
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:SurvivorRatio=6
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-Xloggc:E:\Tomcat7\gc.log
```

I'm using CMS as garbage collector and the behavior seems to be very strange. Even having 13GB of Old generation, when a major collection is performed (I guess at 90% of occupied space -> -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=90) , CMS is not able to clean a large amount of objects (still having occupied space of at least 7GB). I don't believe that application has so many long-lived objects (not sure!). Is it not supposed that CMS release much more space? Or could be something related to fragmentation?

Because of this behavior I'm having frequent CMS cycles...that I would like to decrease.

Even using a low pause GC, sometimes application stops 15-30 secs... How can I decrease pause time in CMS? 
Could be a good idea to have more JVMS instead of having one with 20GB of heap?

Thanks a lot

Comment: do you really need 7GB heap? Reasonable for GC IS 2 GB. Max 4gb , can you pls post  gc log. I am worry that you should decrease  CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction because it looks like that CMs is not able to make major collection and switch to serial one, are you sure that there is no memory leek?

Comment: The heap size is 20GB. The application is generating almost 5GB of objects in each minute (high-load and a lot of short-lived objects are created).I'll add the GC log in another post. Thanks!

Comment: Please find in this URL the GC log http://www17.zippyshare.com/v/42614853/file.html

Answer (score 0):

First, you can dump the heap dump file with:

```
jmap -heap:live heap.bin ${pid}
```

command and find the long-lived objects by mat

Second, because the heap size is bigger than 8G and you can try Garbage First(G1) Collector